# How can I change AlertDialog width and how can I close it when clicked out of alertdialog?

Tags: android

I want to change width of this DialogFragment and also I want to close it when I clicked outside of dialogbox.

Here is my code

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View v;


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom,null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(v).setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });



        return builder.create();


    }
}
```

and here is my custom.xml and here is my custom.xml
vand here is my custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillViewport="false">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grafikler"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:baselineAligned="false">




        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pozitif"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/negatif"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/duz"
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/oo_golge"
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/os_golge"
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tg_gunes"
            android:id="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tg_golge"
            android:id="@+id/imageView15"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tas"
            android:id="@+id/imageView16"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView15"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/expres"
            android:id="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView16"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/expres2"
            android:id="@+id/imageView18"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/expres3"
            android:id="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView18"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/exprescok"
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Negatif Yüzey"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Pozitif Yüzey"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Düz Yüzey"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Öğleden Önce Gölge"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Öğleden Sonra Gölge"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView13" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Tüm Gün Güneş"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView15"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView14" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Tüm Gün Gölge"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView16"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView15"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView15" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Taş Düşme Riski"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView16"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="5-10 Express"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView18"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView17" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="10-20 Express"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView18"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView18" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="20-30 Express"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView19" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="30-40 Express"
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView20" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you show the custom layout xml code as well please?

Comment: The title of your question is about AlertDialog, but you ask about DialogFragment - that is misleading, you should correct that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the width of the dialog, you can override onStart() method of the MyDialog class.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);    
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
        int width = CUSTOM_WIDTH;
        int height = CUSTOM_HEIGHT;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
}
```

To dismiss dialog when clicking outside, please use this code:
`DialogFragment.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

Must be called in onCreateView.

Hope this code will be of help to you

Comment: one more thing how can i chane custom_width to wrap_content?? for example when i put 400 in width it is ok for nexus one  but it is not ok for nexus6

Comment: Yes,

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);